# Function to select all checkbox in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid and the first column I have a checkbox (checkAll others checkbox). I don't know how i do it. How I do a function to select all others checkbox in my jqgrid?

```
$.getJSON("/Page/Table", function (data) {
        var data = data;
        $('#table').jqGrid({
            datatype: 'local',
            data: dados,
            colNames: ['<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" onclick="checkBox(event)" />', 'UserName', 'Code', 'Email'],
            colModel: [
                        {
                            name: 'checkbox',
                            width: 50,
                            resizable: true,
                            editable: true,
                            align: 'center',
                            edittype: 'checkbox',
                            formatter: "checkbox",
                            formatoptions: { disabled: false },
                            classes: 'check',
                            editrules: { required: false }, editoptions: { size: 39, value: "True:False" }
                        },
                        { name: 'userName', width: 200, index: 'userName', align: 'left' },
                        { name: 'code', width: 80, index: 'code' },
                        { name: 'Email', width: 150, align: 'left', index: 'Email'}],
            viewrecords: true,
            imgpath: 'jqGrid-3.4.3/themes/coffee/images',
            caption: '',
            rownumbers: true,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 1860,
            scrollOffset: 0
        });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably it would be better to use `multiselect: true` option which will create the column with checkboxs in the grid? All functionality which you try to implement seems be directly in the grid.

Comment: @user2919627: You are welcome! By the way `imgpath` option don't exist at all. You can remove `caption: ''`. You can also remove `scrollOffset: 0` if you use `height: 'auto'`. I don't recommend you insert `index` and `align: 'left'` because of removing it make the same results. The smaller is your code the better.

Comment: But now, how do i know the checkbox is checked?

Comment: @user2919627: There are callbacks `onSelectRow` and `onSelectAll` (or events `jqGridSelectRow` and `jqGridSelectAll`) which you can use.

Comment: But how i use onSelectRow and onSelectAll (or events jqGridSelectRow and jqGridSelectAll)?

Comment: @user2919627: You should look at [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events) or just search for `onSelectRow` of the stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

by using common class for checkboxes using jquery we can do

```
$('.check').attr('checked', true);
```

Comment: I can get all the values ​​of the checkbox, but I can not select them

Answer (score 0):

Modify the first `colNames` as:

```
colNames: ['<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" onclick="checkBox(this)" />',
```

and the **JS** function as this:

```
function checkBox(obj) {
    $('.check').prop('checked', obj.checked);
}
```

Comment: SyntaxError: missing formal parameter
 

function checkBox(this) {

Comment: Yes. Now it's: '<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" onclick="checkBox(this)" />' and the function is: function checkBox(this) {
        $('.check').prop('checked', checked);
    }

Comment: The js function is not correct, it should be like : `function checkBox(obj) {
    $('.check').prop('checked', obj.checked);
}`